# How can I create a list similar to random.sample using numpy seed

Tags: python, numpy, random, seed

I wanted to create a list(length of list 100) of unique random number from say range 0 to 100, such that no number repeats twice.
I know I can do that it using `random.sample()`

```
block = random.sample(range(0,100),100)
```

But I wanted to use seed in this, so I wanted to use numpy random seed and generate 100 unique numbers from a given set.

Comment: I don't see what `seed` has to do with this.  Your aren't using seed with `random`, so you shouldn't need it with `np.random`.

Comment: @hpaulj I needed it for another block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

```py
np.random.seed(123456)
l = list(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need numpy for this. Python's `random` library allows you to set the seed as well.

```py
random.seed(5)
block = random.sample(range(0, 100), 100)
```

Comment: `shuffle` (per user17242583's comment) seems the natural thing to use here, but I agree that numpy is not needed. Maybe `random.seed(5); block = list(range(0,100)); random.shuffle(block)`

Comment: @rchome I know I can use random.sample(), but I needed to use random seed from numpy.

Comment: @SumitSomani Just wondering, why do you need numpy for this?

Comment: @rchome I just needed seed, I thought seed is available only with numpy module, but I just understood that seed can work with numpy as well as random module as well. Now just an another question to folks here, what is the difference with seed with numpy module and seed with random module?

Comment: @SumitSomani Each module has their own random number generator with different implementations, so keep track of their own separate seeds. `np.random.seed` only affects results from `np.random` functions while `random.seed` only affects results from Python's `random` library.